# In what scenario will a decision tree intuitively perform better than a random forest?

Tags: random-forest, cart, model-evaluation

I was asked this question in an interview, not convinced about what the answer will be.

In what scenario (or under which conditions) will a decision tree (intuitively) perform better than a random forest?

What I understood is the interviewer wanted a theoretical scenario where DTs will outperform RFs. I mentioned sample size but he was not convinced with the answer. TIA for the help.

Comment: Since I see no mention of the word *prediction*, the most obvious answer I can think of is: *when the user wants to do inference*. This is far easier in a tree than in a forest.

Comment: He did mention that about performance, so I guess that should consider predictions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never, if you set the hyperparameters of a random forest perfectly.

By definition a simple decision tree can be seen as a random forest with one single tree and with specific hyperparameter specifications.

You should have asked them what they mean with "perform better" because this is not very exact.